# Marcar leído una publicación

Tags: wordpress

¿Hay una manera de marcar con una imagen o tilde como leida/vista una pagina de la web ? Unicamente encontre mediante plugin pero no me resultan. 
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías detallar un poco más tu pregunta por favor

Comment: Si claro! Arme una pagina en la cual de un lado tengo un listado de objetos con un enlace " Mas detalles" .Del otro lado de la pagina hice un frame que me hace de preview al enlace  "Mas detalles". Yo necesito marcar cual pagina se vio y cual no (frame). Ya que si se loguea otro dia quiero que vea que ese no fue leido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes darle un estilo con CSS a un enlace visitado por el usuario con la pseudo-clase :visited.

Aquí encontrarás más información:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: Podrías utilizar lo que comenta RockoDev de la pseudoclase `:visited` y con Javascript detectar las url que ya visitaste y agregar algún otro elemento HTML al contenedor de tu nota.